# How can I combine Handles in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, io, subprocess

I'd like to have something like bash's `2>&1` redirect in Haskell that combines `stdout` and `stderr` from a process into a single `Handle`. It would be nice to do this directly with `System.Process.createProcess` or a similar library function, particularly if it used the same semantics as the bash redirect w.r.t. interleaving input from the handles.

The flexibility offered by `createProcess` seems promising at first: one can specify a `Handle` to use for the standard file descriptors, so the same `Handle` could be given for both `stdout` and `stderr`. However, the `Handle` arguments must already exist before the call. Without the ability to create a `Handle` from thin air before calling the function, I'm not sure the problem can be solved this way.

**Edit:** The solution needs to work regardless of platform.

Comment: Do you need a cross-platform approach? Or will this just be running on a unix-y system?

Comment: @camccann Yep; updated the question accordingly.

Comment: Well, [here's the answer you would have gotten](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/unix/2.4.2.0/doc/html/System-Posix-IO.html) otherwise. Technically this works if you have a compatibility layer like cygwin, but that's... eugh.

Comment: Eugh indeed. I'm working on a system that uses such things currently, and the motivation for this question is so I can move to a more portable approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [here](http://nominolo.blogspot.fr/2010/04/haskell-tip-redirect-stdout-in-haskell.html):

```
import GHC.IO.Handle   -- yes, it's GHC-specific
import System.IO

main = do
  stdout_excl <- hDuplicate stdout
  hDuplicateTo stderr stdout  -- redirect stdout to stderr

  putStrLn "Hello stderr" -- will print to stderr
  hPutStrLn stdout_excl "Hello stdout" -- prints to stdout
```

Comment: Great! I probably missed this because of the GHC-specific library

Answer (score 4):

Getting your hands on a `Handle` isn't too hard: `System.IO` offers constants `stdin,stdout,stderr :: Handle` and functions `withFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> (Handle -> IO r) -> IO r` and `openFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> IO Handle`.

Alternately, you could request new pipes from `createProcess` and set yourself up as a forwarding service (reading from the new `stdout` and `stderr` handles of your child and sending both to wherever you like).

Answer (score 2):

Since Windows supports [`pipe (3)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edze9h7e%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) natively and GHC's IO library [uses CRT file descriptors internally on Windows](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/blob/master/GHC/IO/FD.hs), it is possible to come up with a solution that works on both Windows and *nix at least. The basic algorithm is:

- Call `pipe`. This gives you two file descriptors which you can convert to `Handles` with [`fdToHandle'`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/GHC-IO-Handle-FD.html#v%3afdToHandle-39-).
- Call `createProcess` with `stdout` and `stderr` both set to the pipe's write end.
- Read child output from the pipe's read end.

The [`System.Posix.Internals`](https://github.com/ghc/packages-base/blob/master/System/Posix/Internals.hs) module, which exports `c_pipe`, is hidden by default, but you can compile a custom version of `base` that lets you access it (tip: use [cabal-dev](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cabal-dev)). Alternatively, you can access `pipe` via FFI. **NB:** this solution is GHC-specific.

Comment: This seems like the way it should be implemented, thanks. I'll experiment with how portable this approach can be.

Comment: @acfoltzer Can you tell us your results?

Comment: @nh2 we wound up limping along with the bash solution, sadly. It would be nice to revisit this at some point, though